# Using case with operators ( =, LIKE)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I want to run the query by selecting value from dropdownlist which consist of `=` and `LIKE`.

Here is the html:-

```
 <td valign="left" width="20%">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlmathsign" runat="server" Style="width: 30%; background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: bottom right; border: solid 1px #ACACAC; font-family: Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Equal">=</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="LIKE">LIKE</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
```

i want a query for `Current_Item_Batch` on the basis of operators user selects from the list.

```
select * from WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK where location_name='A1132' or Current_Item_code='4059010' or (CASE WHEN Current_Item_Batch = 'what query should come here ???'
```

I tried with `case` with below query but it didn't worked for me

```
"select * from WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK where " +
                     "location_name='" + ddlBin.SelectedValue + "' or Current_Item_code='" + ddlItem.SelectedValue + "' or "+
                     "(CASE WHEN Current_Item_Batch = " + ddlmathsign.SelectedValue + " then Current_Item_Batch='" + txtBatch.Text + "'";
```

Please suggest what is going wrong here

I am using **SQL server 2005**

Comment: First of all, the worst thing is that in 2015 your sql code still could easily be injected.

Comment: Also, 'didnt work' is a poor explanation of what is wrong here.

Comment: @AgentFire: I am getting error as `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '='.`

Comment: If you're using dynamic SQL, shouldn't you do the operation logic in the code that builds the dynamic SQL, instead of doing the operator comparisons in SQL?

Comment: @JamesZ; can you explain of how to do that

Comment: By using if statement? I don't understand what your problem is, if you have like selected, then add correct where clause to the SQL, and if equal is selected then add suitable SQL for that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not in front of a computer but here is an idea. This is just a pseudo code of course, but you will see how to construct the statement instead of  a case expression:

```
or (@selecteditem = 'equal' and Current_Item_Batch = 'txtBatch.Text')
or (@selecteditem = 'like' and Current_Item_Batch like '%txtBatch.Text%')
```

Or you can generate sql statement on the fly:

```
..."' or Current_Item_Batch " +
      ddl.selectedvalue == "equal" ? (" = '" + txtBatch.Text + "'") :
                                     (" like '%" + txtBatch.Text + "%'")
```

When dealing with such a costructions of statements always think about injection threat.

Comment: i tried `"select * from WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK where " +
                         "location_name='" + ddlBin.SelectedValue + "' or Current_Item_code='" + ddlItem.SelectedValue + "' or " +
                         "" + ddlmathsign.SelectedValue + " = 'Equal' and Current_Item_Batch = '" + txtBatch.Text + "'" +
                         "'" + ddlmathsign.SelectedValue + " = 'LIKE' and Current_Item_Batch LIKE '%" + txtBatch.Text + "%'";` but i am running at incorrect syntax

Comment: i am trying 1st one. can you help me with the dynamic code. It is givin g syntax error Please `"select * from WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK where " +
                         "location_name='" + ddlBin.SelectedValue + "' or Current_Item_code='"
                         + ddlItem.SelectedValue + "' or '"
                         + ddlmathsign.SelectedValue + "' = 'Equal' and Current_Item_Batch = '" + txtBatch.Text + "' or '" + ddlmathsign.SelectedValue + " and Current_Item_Batch = '%" + txtBatch.Text + "%'";`

Comment: `ddlmathsign.SelectedValue + " and Current_Item_Batch = '%" + txtBatch.Text + "%'";`  you didn't check ddlvalue. Should be something like  `ddlmathsign.SelectedValue + "' ='like' and Current_Item_Batch = '%" + txtBatch.Text + "%'";`  you miss some parentesis also to make logic correct. See the variable before executing to verify generated sql. But second approach is better.

Comment: but second approach is only running the LIKE query not the whole select query. why ?

Comment: Did you just copy pasted? There are 3 dots hich means your prev statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93854/discussion-between-coder-and-giorgi-nakeuri).